# Echart React legend icon and label custom Styling

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am using Echarts library in react for charts but some custom styling I cannot find on internet and I want to apply them on Legend icon of pie chart

These are picture of styling that I want on icon

1. in this image there is box shadow under icon and icon are bigger [image: 1st]
2. in this picture icon is square and e chart offers rect but not square (I think) [image: 2nd]
3. and this one is about label it is away from line [image: 3rd]

My code for First problem

```
option={
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
  },
  legend: {
    top: '30%',
    right: '10%',
    icon: 'circle',
    orient: 'vertical',
    textStyle: {
      color: '#4E4B66',
      width: 120,
      fontSize: '14px',
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      overflow: 'break'
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: name,
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['40%', '70%'],
      avoidLabelOverlap: false,
      itemStyle: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      label: {
        show: false,
        position: 'center'
      },
      labelLine: {
        show: false
      },
      color: colorPalette,
      center: ['30%', '50%'],
      data: data
    }
  ]
}
```

For 2nd problem

```
option={
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
  },
  legend: {
    top: 'bottom',
    textStyle: {
      color: '#969BA0',
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      fontWeight:600
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: name,
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '50%',
      data: data,
      color: colorPalette2,
    }
  ]
}
```

for 3rd problem

```
label:{
  formatter: '{title|{c}}{abg|}',
  backgroundColor: bg,
  borderRadius: 90,
  color: '#fff',
  width: 35,
  height: 35,
  rich: {
    title: {
      align: 'center'
    },
    abg: {
      width: 35,
      height: 35,
    },
  }
}
```